# 192.168.1.254 vs 255 DHCP IP assignment

Tags: ip, dhcp

I belive that with a 255.255.255.0 subnet you get 255 ip addresses. Whats the difference between DHCP servers that use "192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.254" and "192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.255"? Are both of these even correct?
If my current DHCP server uses "192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.254" are there any impicatons when changing to "172.16.0.0 to 172.16.255.255"

Comment: 192.168.1.255 and 172.16.255.255 in your examples are reserved as broadcast addresses and should not be assigned to a particular host.

Comment: @DavidPostill  according to RFC 1918 172.16 is /12  so the broadcast might not be as straight forward as 172.16.255.255  Try 172.31.255.255  and to check ones maths is right, that is mentioned here too http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address

Comment: This little trick may help you remind it: Think of it as a router: 0 is for the device itself using administrative access (The subnet) and 255 is for the main network cable/access from an external network (broadcast). Anything in between is for the actual network, where one of the addresses is used as physical address to contact the device by regular usage.

Comment: @LPChip Say you access your router  192.168.0.1 to administrate it(clearly not a subnet address). Can you explain how that fits in with you saying "0 is for the device itself using administrative access (The subnet)"  ?

Comment: @barlop: see it as a shell outside of the network. The 0 being the shell, the 255 being the access to it. The shell has an opening, which is the ip address for the device itself, being your 0.1 (or any other ip in that range)

Comment: @LPChip You write "see it as a shell outside of the network." <-- what kind of shell. A command line shell, like telnet? Still not .0(still eg 192.168.0.1) u write "The 0 being the shell, the 255 being the access to it." <-- Now u r just talking gibberish like you are talking in a dream in another dimension. You haven't given any evidence of a subnet address being the IP of the device(which you claimed). Your comment said that the subnet address was for administration but I gave you an example to show that it is not(not in my experience anyway). What model of router have you found it to be?

Comment: Lol @barlop No, a phyisical shell. Something that encapsulates something else. It was meant metaphorically. Meant to say something technical using non-technical terms. I was not going to provide an actual answer because an excellent answer already has been given. Its just a way to remember it.

Answer (score 5):

You write

> "I belive that with a 255.255.255.0 subnet you get 255 ip addresses"

You mean a subnet with a mask of 255.255.255.0

You get 254 addresses to use for hosts.   0 is identifying the subnet..  255 is the broadcast.

There are 256 numbers from 0-255. Take the 256, subtract 2, the subnet and broadcast addresses, and you have 254 addresses available for hosts, when using a mask of 255.255.255.0

> You write "Whats the difference between DHCP servers that use
>   "192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.254" and "192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.255"?"

No DHCP server would assign 192.168.1.255  as  that is the broadcast address

The 172.16  is a bit obscure.. see RFC 1918

> ```
>  10.0.0.0        -   10.255.255.255  (10/8 prefix)
>  172.16.0.0      -   172.31.255.255  (172.16/12 prefix)
>  192.168.0.0     -   192.168.255.255 (192.168/16 prefix)
> ```

192.168 is 255.255.0.0 but you can have a subnet that is 255.255.255.0 as you do.

So for 255.255.255.0 that's /24 leaving 8 bits. 2^8 is 256. minus two as mentioned so 254.

Apply that to the 172.16
So 12 bits for the network. That leaves 20 bits for the host.

2^20 = 1048576 IP addresses.  subtract 2, one for the subnet one for the broadcast.

1048574 IP addresses for hosts.

If you used 172.16.1.0 as your subnet then that could be a 255.255.255.0 address so again, 254 IPs for hosts

But the 172.16.0.0/12 subnet if you're going to use the /12 and not make it a /16(255.255.0.0) or /24(255.255.255.0), then the broadcast would actually be 172.31.255.255    That is due to how  masks are calculated including more complex masks like /12, but there's often no need to use subnet masks that aren't /8 /16 /24

Comment: Thanks, you explained that nicely. I'll still have to do more reading to understand more thoroughly but this helps a tonne.

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents: Note that you can *send* information to a broadcast address; Your computer will automatically sent the packet to the entire network, any computer listening for broadcasts will receive them. Applications like Dropbox and XBMC, as well as protocols like UPNP and Windows' neighbor discovery (this is how other windows computers on the same network show up under Network Locations) use this to discover other machines on the same network to directly share data with.

IPv6 does not have a broadcast address anymore, just multicast.. but that's another story.

Comment: Wow, OK, thats interesting. Can I leverage that in my applications? Or is it an advanced feature?

Comment: @alex re your first sentence it's worth noting that nobody denied that. Re your second sentence, more like the computer will send it out addressed to the entire subnet, and the commonly, network switch will send it out to all.

Comment: @jamesbaber you should learn about hubs and switches a bit more. I don't know what you could possibly have thought a broadcast was if what Alex said was news to you.

Comment: @jamesbaber Yes! Many applications use it :) Do note that some special rules apply; it doesn't travel past a router (only works on a single subnet), and some firewalls handle broadcast packets differently. Do note that in IPv6 there isn't really an analogue to broadcasts, just multicasts, which is similar but not the same. Google for "multicasting" if you want to learn more about it.

Comment: @Alex Awesome, can't wait to implement that into my next networking application

Comment: @barlop I wasn't implying anyone denied it, just worth noting. Also note that the broadcasting the switch does is only at MAC level (i.e ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff), the OS still has to convert the IP address to a broadcast packet and set the right flags and such.

Comment: When you write "convert the IP address to a broadcast packet and set the right flags and such" <-- You should be a lot clearer 'cos converting an IP address into a broadcast packet sounds like "I drove to work on my felt tip pen".Like converting a home address into a poem.It's almost chalk and cheese.And by flags? qualify flags.eg not tcp flags? then what flags And since i'm not sure what process u are talking about (google gives nothing for the phrase u used-u did not phrase yourself well at all), and when you say OS,u should specify what device(s)u are referring to.Saying OS doesn't say much

Comment: @barlop The reason my original Answer is short was because I didn't want to load him up with too much at the same time and just add my two cents.. Plus comments aren't made for this stuff, and networking can get pretty complex. I figured just saying 'your computer will send it to the rest of the network' would be easier to understand than 'your networkcard will convert the OSI stack level 3 broadcast packet to a OSI stack level 2 broadcast packet, and defer the broadcasting of the actual data to the nearest switch' or something along those terms, I just wanted to stick to the basics.

Comment: @Alex I agree he won't understand that(but he won't mistakenly think he does),but ur phrasing was even more unclear.At least if you use the technical terms of encapsulation and decapsulation then he'd have the terms to look up.There may be a clearer simpler way but the way you put it didn't make much sense even in simple terms.Like saying convert a home address into a poem.  It has been a while since I looked at the technicalities so i'm not sure off hand what flags u r referring to,but if u explained what you meant thenI might be able to show you a simpler way to put it(that makes sense).